# What are the names of $F_{\sigma},G_{\delta}$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

$F_{\sigma}$ denotes a countable union of closed sets and $G_{\delta}$ denotes a countable intersection of open sets.

I can see that there is a different use of article for them. For instance, every half-open interval $[a,b)$ is 'a' $G_{\delta}$ and 'an' $F_{\sigma}$.

Not only this, since i'm a self-studying mathematics, there are some difficulties with notions. Is there a website for notions of mathematics? For example, I can see that some latin word similar to M (I don't know how to type this in Latex) is generally used to denote $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$, but i have no idea what it is called.. Should i just read it as 'M'? Moreover, i really want to know how other people write latin words. For instance, when you write 'n', you start drawing from the left top, not the right top.

Comment: Read Walter Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* and in the first chapter you'll get that.

Comment: @Frank I'm reading Rudin's book right now. It just says, "Notation is due to Hausdorff and $\sigma$ refers to the union and $\delta$ to intersection. Where does he say what they are called? I don't understand why Rudin call it " 'a' $G_{\delta}$", but " 'an' $F_{\sigma}$".

Comment: @Katlus, it is because in English words that start with vowels are prefixed by the article "an" and words that start with consonants are prefixed by the article "a".  The letter G is pronounced like "gee" (a soft "g", same as "jee") and F is pronounced like "eff".  Since "eff" starts with a vowel, one would say "an eff".

Comment: It's worth noting that the a/an distinction is due to phonemic vowels rather than orthographic ones. For example although you say "an umbrella", you say "a union", because "union" has a hidden "y" sound at the front of it. On another note, I wonder if these questions are better suited to [Linguistics SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Dan,Martin Exactly.. Thank you. However i didn't ask why there is a use of 'an' to designate a singular noun starts with a vowel instead of 'a'. See my comment below.

Comment: It is difficult as an English speaker to pronounce the glottal stop in "a elephant".  So the convention is to use "an" instead of "a", which mean exactly the same thing.  As Clive points out, the rule depends on the pronunciation of the word, not its spelling (e.g. union = "yoonion", F = "eff").  Linguistics.SE will have a more accurate explanation I am sure.

Comment: @Dan I know that! As i said above, I thought there is a special name to denote $F_{\sigma}$, say 'elegant set' or whatever. I didn't ask why there is 'an' in front of a noun starts with a vowel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say a $G_\delta$ as "a gee sub delta" and an $F_\sigma$ as "an eff sub sigma".  You can also do without the "sub" if the context is established or if there is a visual reference.  $\mathscr{M}$ can be pronounced the same as "M": it is the same letter written in a calligraphic font.

Comment: I couldn't even think this is the reason why.. I thought there is a name for $F_{\delta}$, which starts with a vowel. Thank you

Comment: @Katlus: The reason for using those letters: $F$ is for French *fermé* (closed), $G$ is for German *Gebiet* (zone, region, used for open sets). The $\sigma$ is the Greek "s" for *sum* (old term for union) and the $\delta$ is the Greek "d" for *Durchschnitt* (intersection). Hausdorff chose those letters in his *Grundzüge der Mengenlehre* (1914). For systems of sets $\mathcal{M}$ used a subscript "s" for finite unions from $\mathcal{M}$ and "d" for finite intersections; the Greek counterparts for countable unions/intersections.

Comment: @Martin, great info!

Comment: On mathoverflow there is [What does the $\sigma$ in $\sigma$-algebra stand for?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74004/) with references. In the comments there are some links and scans.